# mysql show db column in multiple returned columns

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a DB table with the following information

ID    CodeID    ItemID    Week
1        1          1        1
2        1          4        2
3        2          1        1
4        2          2        2

I want the result of my query to be grouped by Code ID.  However I want a new column that shows each weeks ItemID.

Example output
CodeID     Week 1    Week 2
  1              1          4
 2              1          2

Any ideas how I can do that?  Thank you.

Comment: It's called a pivot query, and mysql doesn't support them. The workarounds are ugly. Do this in your client code instead, since it's a DISPLAY problem, not an actual data/query problem.

Comment: Search for `[mysql] pivot` on SO to find many other solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know already that you only have two values for the week, you could use this query:

```
SELECT
  CodeID,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Week=1 THEN ItemID END) Week1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Week=2 THEN ItemID END) Week2
FROM
  yourtable
GROUP BY
  CodeID
```

but if the number of weeks is not known, you should use a dynamic query, like this:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    'SELECT CodeID,',
    GROUP_CONCAT(
      DISTINCT
      CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN Week=', Week, ' THEN ItemID END) Week', Week)),
    ' FROM yourtable GROUP BY CodeID;')
FROM
  yourtable
INTO @sql;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Please see [fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06bd7/1).

**Edit**

If there are multiple items in the same week, you could use GROUP_CONCAT aggregated function instead of MAX:

```
SELECT
  CodeID,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Week=1 THEN ItemID END) Week1,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Week=2 THEN ItemID END) Week2
FROM
  yourtable
GROUP BY
  CodeID;
```

Comment: This did the trick!  Thanks.. Howver, what if I had multiple items for in a specific week.. how could I alter this for that?

Comment: this helps me since it may be an unknown amount of weeks.. but i was wondering how to show multiple items inside of a single week.

Comment: @TomD oh sorry I didn't read your comment carefully... i've edited my answer, now it should return what you are looking for... of course, you can also fix my dynamic query to use GROUP_CONCAT instead of MAX

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) ,`CodeID`,`Week` FROM table_name GROUP BY `CodeID`
```